# unpublishing enum in javadoc in java

Tags: java

I have declared enum in my class like this

```
/**
 * Preference type to check the doc
 * 
 * @unpublished
 */
public enum TCPreferenceType
{
    /** String preference. */
    STRING_TYPE,

    /** Logical preference. */
    LOGICAL_TYPE,

    /** Integer preference. */
    INTEGER_TYPE,

    /** Double preference. */
    DOUBLE_TYPE,

    /** Date preference. */
    DATE_TYPE,

    /**
     * Defines an invalid preference type.
     */
    INVALID_TYPE;

    /**
     * @param preferenceType preference type
     * @return type
     * @unpublished
     */
    public static TCPreferenceType convertType( int preferenceType )
    {
        if( preferenceType == 0 )
        {
            return STRING_TYPE;
        }
        if( preferenceType == 1 )
        {
            return LOGICAL_TYPE;
        }
        if( preferenceType == 2 )
        {
            return INTEGER_TYPE;
        }
        if( preferenceType == 3 )
        {
            return DOUBLE_TYPE;
        }
        if( preferenceType == 4 )
        {
            return DATE_TYPE;
        }

        Assert.isLegal( false, "Invalid preference type encounter - " + preferenceType );
        return INVALID_TYPE;
    }
```

I want this should not get published in javadoc.
I have return @unpublished then also it is showing in java doc.
Is there any way to unpublished it.??
Even if it is publish ,is there any way it is not shown with hyperlink?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#exclude): "There is currently no Javadoc option to hide, exclude or suppress public members from the javadoc-generated documentation."

Comment: This enum is shown with hyperlink  in javadoc and when we click on  it ,it takes to error page as there no other details to show. Is there anyway we can show enum without hyperlink ??So that it will be not misleading to user who is using javadoc..

Comment: when we write @unpublished to the public function it is not getting displayed in javadoc. Can we not do similar with the Enum??

Answer (score 1):

The tool `javadoc.exe` generates `javadoc` depending on the comment `/**`

using `/*` instead of `/**`

it will be ok!

Comment: This enum is shown with hyperlink in javadoc and when we click on it ,it takes to error page as there no other details to show. Is there anyway we can show enum without hyperlink ??So that it will be not misleading to user who is using javadoc.

Comment: when we write @unpublished to the public function it is not getting displayed in javadoc. Can we not do similar with the Enum??